# Examples of non-polynomial comonads on Set?

Tags: ct.category-theory, examples, polynomial-functor, comonad

---

**Question:** What are examples of comonads on $\mathbf{Set}$ that are *not* polynomial?

---

#### Background: polynomial functors and comonads on Set

A functor $F\colon\mathbf{Set}\to\mathbf{Set}$ is called *polynomial* if it is a sum of representables, i.e. if there is some set $I$ and for each $i:I$ a set $S_i$ and a natural isomorphism
$$
F(X)\cong\sum_{i:I}\mathbf{Set}(S_i, X)
$$
over $X:\mathbf{Set}$.

For example, $X\mapsto X^2$ is polynomial, because we can take $I:=\{\bullet\}$ and $S_\bullet:=\{1,2\}$ and
$$X^2\cong\mathbf{Set}(\{1,2\},X)\cong\sum_{i:\{\bullet\}}\mathbf{Set}(S_i,X).$$
Similarly the constant functor $X\mapsto 2$ is polynomial because we can take $I:=\{1,2\}$ and $S_1=S_2:=\varnothing$.

A comonad on $\mathbf{Set}$ is a tuple $(F,\epsilon,\delta)$ where $F\colon\mathbf{Set}\to\mathbf{Set}$ is a functor, $\epsilon\colon F\to\mathsf{id}_\mathbf{Set}$ and $\delta\colon F\to F\circ F$ are natural transformations, and these satisfy the usual "comonoid" laws, coassociativity and counitality.

#### Setup: It's easy to find polynomial comonads

There are many polynomial comonads on $\mathbf{Set}$; in fact, a result of Ahman and Uustalu says that they are in bijection with categories: every category can be identified with a polynomial comonad and vice versa.

But what about *non-polynomial* comonads? Picking up on [Mathoverflow: "Big list of comonads"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328513/big-list-of-comonads), which asks for comonads from all around math, I ask a much more refined question.

#### Question:

$\quad$ What are examples of comonads on $\mathbf{Set}$ that are *not* polynomial?

Comment: I edited to make the second iso in the second displayed line an equality, but then realized that depending on how we define unary coproducts it perhaps should be an iso; if the edit was in error I apologize.

Comment: Perhaps this should be a community wiki answer instead?

Comment: @AlecRhea: I’ve rolled back the edit — whether it’ll actually be an equality or iso here is a slightly fiddly question (since the coproduct here is a special case of an arbitrary set-indexed coproduct, I think under most constructions it won’t be one, but one could reasonably special-casd the unary ones) — but the main point is that it doesn’t matter, the isomorphism is really what we need — so whenever the question is at all subtle, it’s better to just leave the iso rather than wasting time worrying about whether it’s an equality.

Comment: Sorry, could not find time to analyze it properly, but it seems there are several comonad structures on $G(X)=X\times2^X$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's something inspired by Simon's answer that gets a ways beyond surjections out of $\mathbf{Set}.$ This is all very much riding the edge of my comfort zone with topos theory so do let me know if something seems wrong. In short, I aim to show below that a pullback-preserving comonad on $\mathbf{Set}$ is the same thing as a Grothendieck topos with enough points, so that the non-polynomial pullback-preserving comonads correspond to the toposes that aren't presheaf toposes.

Let $X$ be a topological space with underlying set $U(X).$ Then there's a geometric surjection $f:\mathbf{Set}/U(X)\to \mathbf{Sh}(X)$ whose inverse image takes all the stalks and whose direct image takes the product of skyscraper sheaves. This makes $\mathbf{Sh}(X)$ comonadic over $\mathbf{Set}/U(X).$ Now $\mathbf{Set}/U(X)$ is also comonadic over $\mathbf{Set},$ with the forgetful functor $\Sigma$ given by summing over the fibers. These comonads compose: since $\Sigma$ preserves connected limits and $f^*$ preserves finite limits, both preserve coreflexive equalizers so we can just use crude comonadicity.

The composite gives a comonad on $\mathbf{Set}$ sending $A$ to the coproduct of all the stalks of the product of all the $A$-shaped skyscraper sheaves: $\coprod_{x\in X}x^*\prod_{x\in X} x_*A,$ whose coalgebras are sheaves on $X.$ (I'm sure this is well known but I'm just working it out for myself; maybe there's another more familiar description.)

Though the formula I just wrote looks awfully polynomial, I claim this usually is not a polynomial comonad. This is fundamentally because taking the stalk doesn't preserve infinite products, which is equivalent to preserving connected limits for a left exact functor. Specifically, if $S$ is a finite subset of $X$ then the stalk $x^*\prod_{x\in S} x_* A$ is $A,$ if $x\in S,$ and otherwise terminal. That means that the limit, over the (connected) category of finite subsets $S,$ of $x^*\prod_{x\in S} x_*A$ is just $A.$ But the stalks of $\prod_{x\in X}x_*A$ are not necessarily $A$ when $X$ is infinite. (For instance, if $A=\{0,1\}$ and $X=\mathbb R,$  consider the germ at $0$ of the section of $\prod_{x\in\mathbb R}x_*\{0,1\}$ that is $1$ on $x_*\{0,1\}$ on any open containing $x,$ except that it's $0$ on $0_*\{0,1\}.$)

I believe this gives a non-polynomial comonad on $\mathbf{Set}$ for every space $X$ whose sheaf category is not equivalent to a presheaf category. I suspect you could extend this argument even further by letting $X$ be the underlying space of a topological groupoid, which would lead to such a comonad for every Grothendieck topos with enough points not equivalent to a presheaf category. Grothendieck toposes with enough points are, I believe, characterized by inducing a pullback-preserving comonad on $\mathbf{Set},$ so this ought to completely cover that case, so that non-polynomial comonads are exactly the disjoint union of the non-presheaf category Grothendieck toposes and the comonads that don't preserve pullbacks.

Comment: I was going to extend my answer to include this as well. You get a comonad like this for every Grothendieck topos and every "sufficient" set of points of that topos (So for "Ionads" in the sense of Garner's https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.1415). Even if the topos is presheaf, this monads will be polynomial only if the chosen points are representble (essentials).

Comment: Ahh, thanks for that clarification, I was definitely thinking of the representable points without noticing:

Comment: I think this fiber product preserving comonad/"ionads" correspondence is a very neat generalization of Ahman and Uustalu's theorem and should be written out in more details somewhere! and maybe functoriality aspects looked at a little more. Are you Interested in collaborating on this? ( Sorry I couldn't find your current email - I believe mine is on my profile.)

Comment: Oops, my profile had gotten quite out of date! Thanks for the suggestion. I'll send you an email.

Comment: This is great, thank you! 

For each such comonad $pts_X: \mathbf{Set}\to\mathbf{Set}$, how does the associated sheaf category $Sh(X)$ compare with algebras of the associated "gluing" monad (which is familial) $\text{glue}_X: Psh(X)\to Psh(X)$ on the presheaf category for the site $Op(X)$?  Happy to ask in a new question if that's preferable. 

And a remedial question if you feel like answering: How does the property of a space's sheaf category being of presheaf type compare with the property that a space is "Alexandrov" over its poset of opens or that of its points?

Comment: @DavidSpivak For the second question, yes I think a sheaf category is presheaf if and only if the space is Alexandrov ie every point is contained in a smallest open. In one direction, sections of a presheaf over the smallest open containing some $x$ aren’t affected by sheafification because such an open has no nontrivial covers, so the stalk at $x$ preserves products and $x$ is an essential point. And a Grothendieck topos is presheaf if and only if it has enough essential points. Conversely, if $x$ is in no minimal open you can imitate the construction in my answer to see $x$ is not essential.

Comment: (…which almost finishes the argument. You just then have to recall that the points of a space are all the points of its sheaf topos.) For the first question, am I missing what you mean by the gluing monad? Not just sheafification, I guess?

Comment: Thanks @KevinArlin! As for the gluing monad, for a category $C$ with a Grothendieck topology $J$, there is a functor $Glue_J: Psh(C)-->Psh(C)$ sending $X$ and an object $U:Ob(C)$ to the set $Glue_J(X)(U)$ given by adding to $X(U)$ a new element for each pair $(V,x)$ where $V$ is a covering family of $U$ and $x$ is a matching family of sections $x_V:X(V)$. The Grothendieck site axioms are exactly what you need to prove that this is a monad.

Answer (score 12):

In general, given a surjective geometric morphism $f: \mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{T}$ of toposes, then the adjunctions $f^* \vdash f_*$ is comonadic.

In particular, given a topological or localic monoid $M$, we have a canonical surjective geometric morphism $Set \to B M$ where $BM$ is the topos of sets endowed with a continuous (smooth) action of $M$.

So, there is a comonad on sets whose category of coalgebras is the category of (smooth) $BM$-sets.

In the case where $M$ is a localic group $G$, the underlying functor sends a set $X$ to the set of functions $G \to X$ that have an open stabilizer in the translation action of G ( so a kind of uniform continuity condition I guess). I assume a similar formula works for a monoids, but I'm less familiar with it so I don't want to claim it.

I think one recovers a polynomial example only in the case where the monoid is discrete... This suggest maybe there is a class of comonads corresponding to some topological categories...

Comment: How do you show that this is polynomial only when the monoid is discrete? I can see how to show it’s non-polynomial in various specific cases, I think, but I don’t see a general argument.

Comment: My reasoning was that for a polynomial comonad the algebra were presheaves categories, and topos of smooth M-Sets aren't. But now that I think about it, it is clear for localic groups, but maybe not so much for localic monoids... I need to think more about it.

Comment: (For e.g. topos of smooth G-set are boolean but don't satisfies AC, while presheaf topos are boolean only if they are presheaves on a groupoid, in which case they satisfies internal AC)

Comment: For groups, at least, you could also do this without any topos theory: if intersections of open subgroups of $G$ aren't always open then the forgetful functor out of continuous $G$-sets doesn't preserve infinite products, which implies it doesn't preserve connected limits (since it preserves the terminal object), so that neither does the corresponding comonad.